# How do I easily and consistently cause an IOError of some sort when reading from or writing to a text file?

Tags: python, file-io, ioerror

I'm teaching an intro programming class in Python, and we're talking about exceptions and file I/O. I'm looking for a way to quickly and simply test their error handling. Now it's easy to cause an IOError when opening a file (just make sure that there is no file with the given filename), but I'd like to be able to test whether or not they're able to handle IOErrors that crop up while reading from or writing to a file, and I can't think of a simple, quick way to ensure that an IOError will occur at that time. I tried using a binary file, which opens fine but causes trouble if you try to read from it, but that causes a UnicodeDecodeError, which is not a type of IOError in Python.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `with open("foo.txt") as f:f.write("foo")` will cause an io error.  opening for writing and trying to read will also cause an io error,`with open("foo.txt","w") as f:for line in f:...`

Comment: You could create a mock file object that injects errors. If you are unit testing, and especially if you are teaching "test first" practices, this would be a good way to go.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without editing the student's source code? That will work, but I was hoping for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Insert some code that rebinds `open()` (and possibly `file`) at the beginning of the code to test:

```
>>> def open(path, *args, **kw):
...     path = os.path.join("/some/path/that/dont/exist", path)
...     return __builtins__.open(path, *args, **kw)
... 
>>> open("foo.bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in open
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/some/path/that/dont/exist/foo.bar'
```